# Equi-distribution of the parity of partitions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, partitions, integer-sequences

The integer partition function $p(n)$ has a generating function given by
$$\frac1{(q)_{\infty}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(n)q^n$$ 
with $(q)_{\infty}=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-q^m)$. The long-standing problem on the *equal appearance* of the parity of $p(n)$ remains a defiant open problem. Subbarao's conjecture on the existence of infinitely many terms, *in each arithmetic progression*,  at which $p(n)$ attains both parities has been considered and proved by K. Ono and others.

We would like to push the claim further beyond Subbarao's *linear* sequences. Therefore, suppose $Q(x)$ is a polynomial (of any degree) with positive integer coefficients.

> **Claim 1.** The sequence $a_n:=Q(n)$ has an infinite subsequence $a_{n_j}$ (resp. $a_{m_i}$) such that $p(a_{n_j})$ is even (resp. $p(a_{m_i})$ is odd).

{}

> **Question.** Can this be proved? Or, is there any info in the literature about it?

**EDIT.** I've dropped Claim 2 because it seems far more difficult (see Joel's comment).

Comment: The question asked in Claim 1 looks interesting. I don't know of any literature on the subject beyond the case $Q$ linear. Question 2 is certainly unprovable now. We don't know yet (and actually the best result are far from) the result of Claim 2 when $c_n$ is the list of integers instead of the list of primes. Restricting to primes just seems to add an additional arbitrary layer of complexity which is unlikely to shed any light.